# Go generate escape characters

Tags: go

I have a go generate directive which looks like this:

```
//go:generate myprog -someName thisname -data 'Request: Typ "." callMe, Rsp:  MyTyp "." close'
```

The issue is that the program receives only value of `-someName` flag ("thisname"). I assume the `-data` flag is discarded for some reasons. Any idea why? It's working if I execute the program directly from command line so I guess it's a go specific issue.

Answer (score 5):

From the design document of go generate https://docs.google.com/document/d/1V03LUfjSADDooDMhe-_K59EgpTEm3V8uvQRuNMAEnjg/edit:

> The arguments are space-separated tokens (or double-quoted strings) passed to the generator as individual arguments when it is run.

So if you want to pass an argument containing space you will have to double quote them. You used single quotes which works in your shell but not with `go generate`

Comment: It seems to be the case though I find it awkward that you can't use single quotes. Now my directive will have several backslash characters to escape the double quotes. Do you think this has any chance as a feature/improvement request or there are good reasons why it doesn't accept single quotes ?

Comment: I doubt that such a feature request would find lots of supporters: Go generate a simple mechanism and after introducing single quotes someone will ask for backquotes and the next one for python-like triple quotes (double and single) just because it make one use of go generate a bit simpler. Go generate is neither for the end user nor for the user of your package: Investing 5 or maybe 15 minutes to properly quote some doublequotes seems okay for a programmer.